# Displaying posts

Tags: php, performance

I am trying to create a new website, and i am using a class  that has many functions on it.
First i want to say that my class has about 5000 rows , is this a  problem ?

The main function  i have used on my class is this one :

```
function f3($id = '') {
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string ($id);
    $sql = 'SELECT id,post_title,post_content,post_date,post_status,term_taxonomy_id,object_id FROM wp_posts, wp_term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id = 60 AND post_status = "publish" AND wp_term_relationships.object_id = id ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2';
    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());    

if (mysql_num_rows($res) !=0):
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res); 


    $mycontent = $row['post_content'];
    $mycontent = strip_tags($mycontent);
    $mycontent = substr($mycontent,0,150);
    $mycontent = preg_replace("/\[caption.*\[\/caption\]/", '', $mycontent); 


    $title = AvinD($row['post_title']);

    $old_date = $row['post_date'];              // returns Saturday, January 30 10 02:06:34
    $old_date_timestamp = strtotime($old_date);
    $new_date = date('d.m.Y   H:i', $old_date_timestamp); 


    $first_img = '';
    $my1content = AvinD($row['post_content']);
    $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $my1content, $matches); 
    $first_img = $matches [1] [0];
    if(empty($first_img)){ //Defines a default image
    $first_img = "/img/default.png";
    }

    echo '
        '.$new_date.'

        <a href="single.php?id='.$row['id'].'"> '.$title.' </a> </div>
         <a href="single.php?id='.$row['id'].'"> <img src="timthumb.php?src='.$first_img.'&amp;h=107&amp;w=190amp;zc=1" alt="" />  </a> </div>
        '.$mycontent.'
    '; //echo

    else:
        echo 'Page dont exist';
    endif;
} // end
```

Also wanted to ask, when should i close the connection with database? at the end of the class? or after every function like this ?

Thank you for reading this post.

Comment: what exactly is the problem, does it not work, does it run slow?

Comment: i am just asking for any improvments if there is any , also the number of rows that i have for my class .. is it a problem ?

Comment: Do you really need to improve response times? remember that `premature optimization is the root of all evil`.

Comment: yes i want improve response times , any suggestion please ?

Comment: When you say "rows in your class", do you mean rows in your database table?

Comment: no i  mean rows in my class class myclass { ......... ...}

Comment: @Meo means 5000 lines of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks fine to me, can't see anything obvious that i would improve on

Normally I don't ever explicitly close a database connection on my scripts.
when the script ends, the database connection is closed automatically

5,000 lines of code for one class is quite a lot, but nothing really wrong with that.
Some people prefer to split them up in to classes which each contain similar functionality, making it easier to find things, but this is not essential.

If you have large methods sometimes it is good to split them up for readability purposes, like if you have to scroll down more then 2-3 pages to see how one functions works.

Answer (score 3):

Seems essentially clean to me as well but I have some minor beefs (beefettes?).

Personally I like descriptive names as it makes reading easier when I have to return to older code for maintenance. Names like `f3` and `AvinD` do not lend themselves for clear interpretation of what they are supposed to do. The separation of `mycontent` and `my1content` is not clear either. Names such as `old_date` and `new_date` are also misleading as they are used to transform the date format not the date value.

I also try to separate responsibilities to different functions. Now `f3` contains

1. Database query handling
2. Data transformation
3. Configuration (default values)
4. Content parsing
5. Template definition
6. Template application
7. Output

It might be beneficial if some of the responsibilities would be in their own functions and the function `f3` would just coordinate the process in a higher level of abstraction e.g.

```
$post_result = find_post($id);
if(found($post_result)):
   $post = fetch_post($post_result);
   $post_id = id_of($post);
   $post_title = title_of($post);
   $post_content = content_of($post); 
   $post_date = format_date_of($post);
   $thumbnail_image = find_first_image_in($post, '/img/default.png');
   echo apply_template($post_id, $post_date, $post_title, $post_content, $thumbnail_image);
 else:
    echo 'Page dont exist';
 endif;
```

In PHP I would be  a bit careful with functions that print out to the output stream. The problem is that you may or may not want/need to set header values at some point. If there's output through out the code then you have a higher risk that some output is already sent to the client before the header values are sent. This will cause a warning to be issued and results in an unexpected behaviour.

Generally, you might want to stay clear of magic numbers. For some reason, the title is truncated to the first 150 characters. Where does that number come from and what does it mean?

You are using the mysql set of functions while you should use mysqli (mysql improved extension). That's just PHP for you.

In SQL, I prefer using JOIN syntax as it forces you to define the join conditions in the immediate context e.g.

```
SELECT 
   id,post_title,post_content,post_date,post_status,term_taxonomy_id,object_id 
FROM wp_posts 
JOIN wp_term_relationships on object_id = id
WHERE term_taxonomy_id = 60 
  AND post_status = "publish" 
ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2
```

I'd like it even more, if the same name was used for both columns (object_id) and you could use `JOIN ... USING (object_id)`.

I'm a bit puzzled why you have escaped the `$id` variable even though you don't use it in the query. Might this be a bug?

I'm not sure why do you want all those columns in the projection if you only use some of them?

When it come to intendation I've come to like that the control statements are on the same level of intendation and blocks are intended one step more e.g.

```
if (mysql_num_rows($res) !=0):
   ...
else:
   ...
endif;
```

The effect of the intendation you used was that I didn't immediately catch the start of the else block.

I see you use `x != 0`. In PHP it's almost always better to use `!==` and `===` instead as they take the type into account as well. You'll save yourself from accidental bugs in the long run.

Lastly there is the case of 5 000 lines (lines of code are called lines instead of rows) in a single class. The length of the class is code smell that suggests that you might not have modelled the problem and the solution quite far enough. I would also be a bit worried that a class that size may have some duplication in it. I would suggest splitting the class though it may increase the total number of lines in the application.